# Pass a Control to a Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, methods

I'm trying to create a method that will custom validate any TextBox control passed to it.

Here's what I've got so far:

A Custom Validator

```
protected void CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        CustomValidator ThisValidator = sender as CustomValidator;
        TextBox MyBox = FindControl(ThisValidator.ControlToValidate) as TextBox;

        args.IsValid = isValid(MyBox);
    }
```

Validation Method

```
protected bool isValid(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox MyBox)
    {
        bool is_valid = MyBox.Text != "";
        MyBox.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        return is_valid;
    }
```

The code compiles OK but I get a

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

on

```
bool is_valid = MyBox.Text != "";
```

When I run the validation.

I know I'm close (well I think I am) but where am I going wrong?

Comment: Line 'TextBox MyBox = FindControl(ThisValidator.ControlToValidate) as TextBox;' - MyBox is null

Comment: Look at FinControl() it's not recursive. I'm not sure why you're using FindControl() there anyway, are you on the page? If so you can put a runat="server" in that sucka and use it by name.

Comment: Sorry, I see you are using it from the custom validator, so you can validate any TextBox.

Comment: @EJC FindControl() was suggested to me as a solution

Comment: @EJC Thanks for your comments which helped the penny drop. All sussed and working.

Comment: Can your firstly separate the code by `bool is_valid; if(MyBox.Text != "") is_valid = true; else is_valid=false;`

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb no problem :) sorry for scrutinizing your usage of `FinControl()` at first :)

Comment: @EJC  That's OK. I'm on a steep learning curve so any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `FindControl()` method is not recursive, therefore `MyBox` is null. You'll have to write a recursive `FindControl()` method like the one [here](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/recursive-findcontrol/) if you want it to work correctly.

You'll probably also want to check if `MyBox` is null and return out of the method if it is.

Answer (score 1):

you first need to check that the object itself exist, after casting:

```
bool is_valid = MyBox != null;
```

and after that you can check its text property

Answer (score 0):

For completeness this code did the trick for me:

```
protected void CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = isValid(txtDeliveryLastName);
    }

    protected bool isValid(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox MyBox)
    {
        bool is_valid = MyBox.Text != "";
        MyBox.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        return is_valid;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

You are trying to validate an empty text box. You can't validate an empty string.

Comment: An empty string will not cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: bool is_valid = MyBox.Text != "";   This will not cause NullReferenceException  ?  

Why not do 
bool is_valid = MyBox.Text != "null"  
like the above poster

Comment: The problem isn't the empty string. It's accessing the `.Text` property of a null object. Look at it another way. Is an empty string a null reference? (No.) Or could the textbox variable contain a null reference? (Yes.) Then ask if you can access a property of a null reference.

Comment: I guess i said it wrong...I meant the null object, not a null string. Yes a string can be empty and not null. Thanks for the correction.